# How to get the greatest Tweets flow?

Tags: twitter

I am working on a project using the Twitter API. I am doing data analysing on Twitter Data. Actually, I have to stream the greatest number of Tweets ever to perform my algorithm on it. Everything works well but I am quite disapointed by the number of Tweets I can actually collect.

By using the STREAMING API, I have only access to around 4500 Tweets each hour in an area like London. The more Tweets I might collect, the better my analysis. I read somewhere that someone was collecting like more than 100,000 each hour...

Do you think my authentification might be rate limited ?

Is SEARCH allows us to collect more Tweets than STREAMING ?

Thank you.